# Sending image from one jsp to another jsp page

Tags: html, image, jsp

I have an image in my jsp page say `<img id="DrawnImage">` and i want to show the same image on another jsp page. How does this work? Thanks.

Comment: why cannot you add the same tag there ? If this is not your problem, describe it better

Comment: I am drawing image on canvas and passing a function which displays image. i want the displayed image to be shown on other jsp page when i click submit without saving it on server. Is it possible?

Comment: check this out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm